# Не могу получить число и дату для бота в телеграмме

Tags: java, xml

Создал метод parseXml для получения курса валют и дату в String.

```
public String parseXml(){
     String nationalB = "Нац. Банк";
  try {
      URL url = new URL("http://www.nationalbank.kz/rss/rates_all.xml");
      URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
      DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document document = documentBuilder.parse(conn.getInputStream());

      NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName("channel");
      String usd = "", course = "", pubDate = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i ++){
          Node node = list.item(i);
          Element element = (Element)node;
          if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
              if (usd == "USD") {
                  course = element.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent();
                  usd = element.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                  pubDate = element.getElementsByTagName("pubDate").item(0).getTextContent();
              }
          }
      }
      return nationalB+" на "+pubDate+"\nДоллар :"+course;

  }catch (IOException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return nationalB;
  }
}
```

Вызываю в методе onUpdateReceived, с помощью переменной usd

```
 public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        String usd = parseXml();
        Message message = update.getMessage();
        if (message != null && message.hasText()){
            switch (message.getText()){
                case "/course for today":
                    sendMsg(message, usd);
                    break;
                case "/setting":
                    sendMsg(message, "Что будем настраивать");
                            break;
                    default:
            }
        }

    }
```

На консоле выводится без проблем(через System.out.println)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в чате не отображается числа.
В чем может быть проблема? 
Может что-то не уследил или не правильно оформил?

Comment: Напишите что выводит в консоли. Попробуйте для дебага просто отправить эту строку методом sendMsg. Если не поможет смотреть строку которую отправляет сам метод. И ещё прочитать код ответа от API, там тоже может быть код ошибки.

Comment: Нац. Банк на 21.01.19
Доллар :378.66
это что выводит в консоли.
(сразу 21-е число выходит- так как на понедельник)
 Пока переменную usd не использую в консоли(не важно).

Comment: Ну так пробовали написать sendMsg(message, "Нац. Банк на 21.01.19 Доллар :378.66"); ?

Comment: Важно понять нет ли в строке спецсимволов. Потому что отправляется на API  это простым GET запросом.

Comment: /*
public void sendMsg(Message message, String text){
        text =  "Нац. Банк на 21.01.19 Доллар :378.66";
        .................
}
*/
 ВОТ ТАК выводит, прям в чате телеграмм(Нац. Банк на 21.01.19 Доллар :378.66)

Comment: Вот сейчас не понял. Вам надо было поменять строку sendMsg(message, usd); на sendMsg(message, "Нац. Банк на 21.01.19 Доллар :378.66");

Comment: Ой прощу прощения. 
sendMsg(message, "Нац. Банк на 21.01.19 Доллар :378.66");
ДА работает, т.е выводит

Comment: Значит проблема всё же в переменной usd. Либо неправильная кодировка, либо есть неотображаемые спецсимволы.  Возможно надо попробовать прогнать через UrlEncoder.